# How Do We Launch Internet Explorer With No Address Bar

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

We have recently migrated from Internet Explorer (IE, henceforth) as our enterprise browser to Chromium Edge (ChrEdge, henceforth). However, we have some web-based applications that still require IE (we're working on updating them to support ChrEdge). We are currently placing icons on the user desktop to launch those applications. However, we are finding that users dislike ChrEdge, mostly just because it's different from IE, and are using those 'launch IE to this site' icons to get an IE window to use IE for things that we no longer wish to allow IE to be used for.

Is there some way to launch IE without the address bar, *without* going into kiosk mode which also forces maximized size, and eliminates the max/min/close and forward/back buttons?

Note that, if group policy is involved, we would prefer a *user*-based solution rather than a *computer*-based solution; our IT personnel do occasionally need to test things in IE and need an unrestricted IE to do so.

Comment: A workaround would be to create a simple HTA application that forwards to the internal web page you want to use (I would assume HTA still uses the IE engine). Those HTA apps are by default without address bar in a window. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application

Comment: @Robert - Please propose this as an Answer; if nothing better comes up before Friday afternoon my time (it's Tuesday morning now), I'll accept. There is the problem that if one clicks on a link on the redirected page, it will open it up in a regular IE window, which we don't want.

Comment: HTAs are going away.  I loved this technology but the only way to use it going forward is in IE9 compatibility mode.  That too will likely go away soon as the entire technology (IE) has been deprecated.  They are very simple to write.. (which is why I love it) but I myself would invest my time in something that will work going forward.  Perhaps a rich client in something like c# that houses your webview window.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - This is _specifically_ for a situation where we temporarily need to continue using IE; once all of our IE applications are corrected, we will be using Group Policy to completely block the use of IE except for our IT personnel. The deprecation and eventual termination of IE in Windows is not a relevant factor for this. For the stuff that doesn't require IE, we are mandating the use of ChrEdge.